# Datepicker can't subtract properly on 2/28?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I don't think I'm hallucinating as I've tried it a dozen times. Here's my code:

```
        $('#teo_prep_due').change(function() {
        var ber = $('#ber_rcvd');
        var tpd = $('#teo_prep_due');
        var brDate = ber.datepicker('getDate');
        var tpDate = tpd.datepicker('getDate');
        var s1Date = new Date();
        var s2Date = new Date();
        var sdDate = new Date();
        s1Date.setDate(brDate.getDate() + 5);
        console.log(s1Date);
        s2Date.setDate(tpDate.getDate() - 3);
        console.log(s2Date);
        if (s1Date < s2Date) {
            sdDate.setDate(s1Date.getDate());
        } else {
            sdDate.setDate(s2Date.getDate());
        }
        $('#survey_due').datepicker('setDate', sdDate);
    });
```

On my date form, I've entered `February 28, 2013` for `ber_rcvd` and `March 14, 2013` for `teo_prep_due`. Following the code, my result should be `March 5, 2013`. However, **s2Date** is resulting in `February 11, 2013`, as if a full month and 3 days are being subtracted instead of just 3 days. Has anyone else run into this?

Using: `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`, `jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js` and `jquery-ui-1.10.1.min.js`.

http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/veP7b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.setDate()` does not set the date, it sets the day of the month. It takes an integer as an argument. When you created `s2Date` it defaulted to today, which is in February. When you add `tpDate.getDate()// equals 14` with -3, you get 11, and therefore February 11th.